# abc.a file not recognized: File format not recognized. error in makefile

Tags: makefile, mingw

I am using mingw compiler. When I execute the makefile I am able to compile and generate object files properly, but I have a problem with linking part. I have 3 library files to include; I am including those lib files, and the error I am getting is:

```
"c:\x\abc.a.file is not recognized:File format not recognized"
```

Here is part of the makefile:

```
LDFLAGS = -Lxxx\
          -LAAA\
          -labc
```

XXX or AAA are the path of lib files to be included.

```
gcc -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS).. (OBJS)
```

contains the list of object files it should generate or consider while generating the target.

Comment: what happens when you try that command on the command line, without Make?

Comment: Please post the line used to compile abc.a

Comment: could you pls tell me what is you `abc` lib full name? `libabc.a`?

Comment: could you please try `gcc $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@`